# Ultimaker CURA moves XYZ at once during travel, how to avoid this?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code, slic3r

I found out that my ancient printer from 2015 (Sharebot NG) stutters when Z is moved with X and Y simultaneously. The printer is one of those where the print head is fixed at the top of the build volume and moves in XY while the plate travels down Z layer by layer.

The printer was originally provided with a Slic3r profile but I want to switch to Cura.

I noticed that during long travel movements, typically the first one where the print head is positioned at the starting point of the print, the printer vibrates a lot.

If the print requires the head to travel long distances, these vibrations eventually shift the plate or tip the print if it's not adequatelly supported, resulting in a failed print.

By comparing the G-Codes from Slic3r and Cura I found that Slic3r moves XY first and then Z separately while Cura does it in a single movement.

Slic3r:

```
  G1 X45 Y50
  G1 Z0.3
```

Cura:

```
  G0 X45 Y50 Z0.3
```

**Is there a way to tell Cura NOT to move the Z axis with X and Y?**

I also tried to understand why the vibration happens by playing with the feed rate and I suspect it's a limitation caused by the firmware or the control board, as it happens even at very low speeds therefore I don't think it's due to insufficient electric current.

Comment: Can you provide more information about where Cura is doing this? Either based on reading the gcode yourself or looking at the gcode preview? My experience has been that it doesn't do this even when it would possibly improve the toolpath, except under very limited conditions.

Comment: it's the very first move after homing, when the head is positioned in the first point of the skirt before the extrusion starts

Comment: Can you just setup your start gcode to end at the initial layer height?

Comment: Interesting, thanks. The problem however could arise in other scenarios too, i.e. if I use z-hop. I'll try